# How to apply tsne() to MATLAB tabular data?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I have a 33000 x 1975 table in MATLAB, obviously requiring dimensionality reduction before I do any further analysis. The features are the 1975 columns and the rows are instances of the data. I tried using tsne() function on the MATLAB table, but it seems tsne() only works on numeric arrays. The thing is that is there a way to apply tsne on my MATLAB table. The table consists of both numeric as well as string data types, so table2array() doesn't work in my case for converting the table to a numeric array.
Moreover, it seems from the MATHWORKS documentation, as applied to the fisheriris dataset as an example, that tsne() takes the feature columns as the function argument. So, I would need to separate the predictors from the resonses, which shouldn't be a problem. But, initially, it seems confusing as to how I can proceed further for using the tsne. Any suggestions in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use [`table` indexing using `{}`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) to get out the data that you want. Here's a simple example adapted from the [`tsne` reference page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/tsne.html):

```
load fisheriris
% Make a table where the first variable is the species name,
% and the other variables are the measurements
data = table(species, meas(:,1), meas(:,2), meas(:,3), meas(:,4))
% Use {} indexing on 'data' to extract a numeric matrix, then
% call 'tsne' on that
Y = tsne(data{:, 2:end});
% plot as per example.
gscatter(Y(:,1),Y(:,2),data.species)
```